# scala get function name that was sent as param

Tags: scala

I have a method that accepts a function as a param. is it possible to extract the function name ?
e.g:

```
def plusOne(x:Int) = x+1
def minusOne(x:Int) = x+1

def printer(f: Int => Int) = println("Got this function ${f.getName}") //doesn't work of course

scala> printer(plusOne) 
Got this function plusOne


scala> printer(minussOne) 
Got this function minusOne
```

Comment: you can do `def printer(f: Int => Int) = println(s"Got this function ${f.getClass.getName}")`

Comment: @RameshMaharjan this will return `<path.to.main>$$anonfun$1`, which is not really helpful

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Functions in Scala don't have names, so you cannot get the "function name" because there *is no* "function name". `plusOne` is not a function, it is a method. Methods and functions are two completely different things. In particular, functions are objects (which means you can pass them as arguments), methods are *not* objects (which means you can *not* pass them as arguments). You have to convert them to a function first … which has no name.

Comment: @JörgWMittag incorrect , this line `printer(plusOne)` will actually works although plusOne is a method

Comment: This is not passing the method `plusOne` as an argument. That cannot possibly work, because only objects can be passed as arguments and methods are not objects. It is performing implicit η-expansion to convert `plusOne` into a partially-applied function. And functions have no names. (Implicit η-expansion is the same as if you had written explicit η-expansion: `printer(plusOne _)`). Seriously, the SLS is pretty clear on this (6.26.2,IV). Doesn't anyone read documentation anymore?

Comment: @JörgWMittag  I see your point , thanks +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not directly. Note that a lambda could be passed as well instead of a function or method name. But you may want to look at the [**sourcecode**](https://github.com/lihaoyi/sourcecode) library, which may help you achieve some of this. For instance:

```
val plusOne = (x: Int) => x + 1
val minusOne = (x: Int) => x + 1

def printer(fWithSrc: sourcecode.Text[Int => Int]) = {
  val f = fWithSrc.value
  println(s"Got this function ${ fWithSrc.source }. f(42) = ${ f(42) }")
}
```

Due to the way implicit conversions work, you cannot use the `def` version directly as in your example. If you have this:

```
def plusOne(x: Int) = x + 1
```

Then you need this:

```
printer(plusOne _)
```

and you'll also see the `_` in the String representation of the parameter.

Note that it also breaks type inference for lambdas, i.e., you can't write this any more:

```
printer(_ * 2)
```

which is a shame.